# Search displaying search results as all products Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I've been working on this search form for an app I'm building to learn Rails.

It's supposed to search for products but when I enter some product name in the search field it gives me a list of all products. The solution is probably simple but I haven't figure it out yet and I'm getting pretty frustrated.

I tried to change @products to a different name but that didn't work.

Can someone check this out and advise me please?

thanks in advance
D

in my _navbar the code is

```
<%= form_tag search_products_path, class: 'navbar-form navbar-right' do %>
  <%= search_field_tag class: 'form-control', :id => 'searchbar',  :placeholder =>'Search', :name => "query" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: 'btn btn-default', :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

in my views/products/search.html.erb

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Designer</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Image</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

 <tbody>
  <% @products.each do |product| %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to product.name, product %></td>
    <td><%= product.description %></td>
    <td><%= product.designer.designer_name %></td>

    <td><%= number_to_currency product.price %></td>
    <td><%= product.stock_quantity %></td>

    <td><%= image_tag product.image.thumb %></td>


 <% end %>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

in my product.rb model I have this code

```
 class Product < ActiveRecord::Base


     mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

     validates_presence_of :name, :price, :stock_quantity
     validates_numericality_of :price, :stock_quantity

     belongs_to :designer
     belongs_to :category
     belongs_to :page

    def self.search(query)
      where("name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%") 
    end


  end
```

In the products_controller.rb I have this code

```
 def search
    @products = Product.search(params[:query])
    @categories = Category.joins(:products).where(:products => {:id => @products.map{|x| x.id }}).distinct

 end
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
 @q = "%#{params[:query]}%"
 @products = Product.where("name ILIKE ? or description ILIKE ?", @q, @q)
```

use

```
 @products = Product.search(params[:query])
```

in model change the code to

```
"name LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?", "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I change the code rails gives me this error `wrong number of bind variables (1 for 2) in: name like ? or description like ?`           in this line         `def self.search(query)
     where("name like ? or description like ?", "%#{query}%") 
    end`

Comment: The syntax is wrong as instead of two variable you are using a single one I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you, it works now but it's still giving me a list of all products instead of just what I searched for,

Comment: try debugging your code what to you find in "%#{query}%"

Comment: Ok, I´m not very experienced with debugging but when it gives me `[1] pry(Product)> query
=> nil
`

Comment: This is the reason why the product list is giving the complete list of products try to find you params[:query] is throwing nil

Comment: Ohh well if I only knew were to start :)